# Cheerio memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, nodes, cheerio

I'm using cheerio to parse the results of otodom.pl advs. I'm experiencing problems regarding memory.

Node 8.10.0 and cheerio@1.0.0-rc.3

4GB RAM, 4GB SWAP, 1 Core, Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-64-generic x86_64)

```
let $ = cheerio.load(context.body.toString());
```

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[10154:0x5607b1d35140]   640026 ms: Mark-sweep 1395.4 (1433.4) -> 1395.3 (1433.9) MB, 2037.1 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[10154:0x5607b1d35140]   641229 ms: Mark-sweep 1395.3 (1433.9) -> 1395.3 (1426.9) MB, 1202.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[10154:0x5607b1d35140]   642829 ms: Mark-sweep 1395.3 (1426.9) -> 1395.3 (1426.9) MB, 1599.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x26de93518fe1 <JSObject>
    1: toString [buffer.js:~609] [pc=0x4ff3cc3e224](this=0xa4360294ad1 <Uint8Array map = 0x100a82c5b801>,encoding=0x26de93502241 <undefined>,start=0x26de93502241 <undefined>,end=0x26de93502241 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 0->3
    3: /* anonymous */ [/home/new/crawler.js:152] [bytecode=0x3a0e68d159b1 offset=70](this=0x2209454880a9 <JSGlobal Object>,context=0xa4360294bf1 <Object m...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x5607b06b5011 [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 6: v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::internal::Vector<char const>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 7: v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::NewStringType, int) [node]
 8: node::StringBytes::Encode(v8::Isolate*, char const*, unsigned long, node::encoding, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) [node]
 9: 0x5607b06d793b [node]
10: 0x4ff3c9f6e47
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a url that sent back a 522 network error. I am looping through 30 urls so I removed the urls one at a time to identify the cause.